# How to setup CORS in ballerina

Tags: cors, wso2, ballerina

When I'm trying to do an Ajax post request to a ballerina service I get the error

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

After looking at the ballerina documentation I tried to use the wild card for the allowOrigins parameter in CORS headers, but still, I get the same error. How can I solve this issue?

Here is my ballerina code for setting the wild card,

```
@http:ServiceConfig { 
basePath: "/path",
cors: {
    allowOrigins: ["*"],
    allowHeaders: ["*"]
}}
```

Headers in my Ajax request is given below

```
headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    }
```

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? Is it the response to the CORS preflight OPTIONS request?

Comment: It's the response for the CORS preflight OPTIONS request

Answer (score 0):

When sending [preflight request](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests) make sure that the request contains both [Origin](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#origin-request-header) and [Access-Control-Request-Method](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-request-method-request-header) headers.

Otherwise the service will not treat the request as a preflight which means the [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header) header will not be included in the service response.
So Client will end up showing following error as it cannot continue with the subsequent POST request

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

According to the given Ajax request, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" has considered as a Request header which is incorrect. It is a response header which supposed to be in the service response